# How to do a JPQL that would filter a collection that does not satisfy a query?

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have a collection `idsToCheck` I want to do something like

```
select a.entry from idsToCheck as a where a.entry not in (select d.id from data d)
```

What I did was for now was

```
@Query("select count(a) > 0 from Data a where a.id = :id")
boolean isIdExists(String id);


idsToCheck 
  .stream()
  .filter(check-> !artifacts.isIdExists(check))
  .forEach(responseBuilder::addDeletedIds);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible with JPQL only but since JPQL does not support SET operations and selects are performed against **entities** (so not against scalars or arrays given as parameters) it might be a complex task to implement.

I realize that my suggestion is not pure JPQL but it is an alternative to yours to have query more abstract. I assume Spring repository interface in my suggestion but guess it is - with minor modifications - applicable elsewhere also.

```
// First fetch all entities in given collection of ids
@Query("SELECT d.id FROM Data d WHERE id in :idsToCheck")
Set<String> findByIds(@Param("idsToCheck") Collection<String> idsToCheck);

// find out which ids were not found at all (the needed SET operation)
default Set<String> findNonExistentIds(Set<String> idsToCheck) {
    idsToCheck.removeAll(findByIds(idsToCheck));
    return idsToCheck;
}
```

With **native query** this should be possible without helper methods.